# prove $(1+\ldots+o(x^{n-1}))^4=(1+\ldots+o(x^{n-1}))$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

> I would like to prove that :
>
> $$(1+\ldots+o(x^{n-1}))^4=(1+\ldots+o(x^{n-1}))$$

i took that from the picture below

[image: reference]

**My Proof:**

note that

$$(1+x)^a = 1 + ax + \frac{a(a-1)}{2!}x^2 + \frac{a(a-1)(a-2)}{3!}x^3 + \cdots + \frac{a(a-1)(a-2)...(a-(n-1))}{n!}x^n + o(x^n)$$

Indeed, let's start with small example  :

$$(1+x+o(x))^4= 1+4x+o(x)$$

$$
\begin{align}
(1+x+o(x))^4&= 1+4x+o(x)\\
\text{ let $x+o(x)=y$ }& \\
(1+x+o(x))^4&= 1+4Y+o(Y)\\
(1+x+o(x))^4&= 1+4(x+o(x))+o(x+o(x))\\
(1+x+o(x))^4&= 1+4x+4o(x))+o(x)+o(o(x))\\
(1+x+o(x))^4&= 1+4x+o(4x))+o(x)+o(x)\\
(1+x+o(x))^4&= 1+4x+o(x))\\
\end{align}
$$

with the same principle we obtain :

$$\begin{align}
(1+\ldots+o(x^{n-1}))^4&=(1+\ldots+o(x^{n-1}))\\
\text{ let $y=\ldots+o(x^{n-1})$ }& \\
(1+\ldots+o(x^{n-1}))^4&= 1+4Y+o(Y)\\
(1+\ldots+o(x^{n-1}))^4&= 1+4(\ldots+o(x^{n-1}))+o(\ldots+o(x^{n-1}) )\\
(1+\ldots+o(x^{n-1}))^4&= 1+(4\times \ldots+4\times o(x^{n-1}))+o(\ldots )+o(o(x^{n-1})) )\\
(1+\ldots+o(x^{n-1}))^4&= 1+ \ldots+ o(x^{n-1})+o(\ldots )+o(x^{n-1}) \\
(1+\ldots+o(x^{n-1}))^4&= 1+ \ldots+o(\ldots )+o(x^{n-1})+ o(x^{n-1}) \\
(1+\ldots+o(x^{n-1}))^4&= 1+ \ldots+o(\ldots )+o(x^{n-1}) \\
\end{align}$$

$$\text{  the termes of $o(\ldots)$ have degree smaller than $o(x^{n-1})$ } \\
(1+\ldots+o(x^{n-1}))^4= 1+ \ldots+o(\ldots )+o(x^{n-1}) $$

- Is my proof correct

**Update :**
Thanks to **Thomas Andrews** for help but i think here is statement of what the paper is claiming:

> If $f(x)=p(x)+o(x^n)$ where $p(x)$ is a polynomial with $p(0)=1$, then:
>   $$f(x)^4 = p(x)^{4} + o(x^n)$$

**Proof:**

note that :

$$o(x^{n})=x^{n}\epsilon (x)\quad \text{ with } \lim_{x\to 0}\epsilon (x)=0 $$
\begin{align}
(p(x)+o(x^n))^4 &=(p(x)+x^n\epsilon(x))^4\\
&=p(x)^4+x^n\left(4p(x)^3 \epsilon(x)+6p(x)^2x^n \epsilon(x)^2+4p(x)x^{2n}\epsilon(x)^3+x^{3n} \epsilon(x)^4\right)\\ 
&= p(x)^4+x^n \epsilon_1(x) \\
&=p(x)^4+o(x^n)
\end{align}

with $\lim_{x\to 0} \epsilon_1(x)=0$

Comment: Unfortunately, what you are trying to prove is a little non-sensical. First, what is in the $\dots$? Is it $o(x)+o(x^2)+\dots$? At the moment, this is all not well-defined.

Comment: Can I rephrase the question for clarity? Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ such that $p(0)=1$. You want to show that if $f(x)=p(x)+o(x^n)$ then:

$$f(x)^4 = p(x)^4+o(x^n)$$

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally, you are trying to prove an imprecise statement without first making it precise. This is very dangerous.

Particularly dangerous are the $\ldots$ on both sides. This statement is not true if the $\ldots$ on both sides are assumed to be the same.

Here is a more precise statement of what the paper/book is claiming:

> If $f(x)=p(x)+o(x^n)$ where $p(x)$ is a polynomial with $p(0)=1$, then:
>   $$f(x)^4 = q(x) + o(x^n)$$
>   where $q(x)$ is a polynomial with $q(0)=1$.

**Proof**:
If $f(x)=p(x)+o(x^n)$ where $p(x)$ is a polynomial with $p(0)=1$, then:

$$f(x)^4-p(x)^4 = (f(x)-p(x))(f(x)^3 + f(x)^2p(x)+f(x)p(x)^2+p(x)^3)$$

But $p(x)\to 1$ and $f(x)\to 1$ so when $x$ is close to zero, this means $|f(x)^3 + f(x)^2p(x)+f(x)p(x)^2+p(x)^3|$ is bounded above by a constant. So:

$$\left|f(x)^4-p(x)^4\right|\leq c|f(x)-p(x)|$$

But $f(x)-p(x)=o(x^n)$, so this means $f(x)^4-p(x)^4=o(x^{n})$, or $f(x)^4=p(x)^4+o(x^n)$.

In particular, you can remove terms from $p(x)^4$ that are of degree $n+1$ or greater, since they are $o(x^n)$, too.

This works more general, if $f(x)=p(x)+o(g(x))$ and $g(x)=o(1)$ and $p(0)=f(0)\neq 0$ then $f(x)^k = p(x)^k + o(g(x))$.

---

Your proof fails, because if $f(x)=1+x+x^2+o(x^2)$ then your $y=f(x)-1=x+x^2+o(x^2)$ and $$1+4y+ o(y) = 1+4(x+x^2) + o(x+x^2+o(x^2))= 1+4x+x^2+o(x)$$

For example, if $f(x)=1+x+x^2+x^3$, then $x^3=o(x^2)$ and $y=x+x^2+x^3$ and notice that $y/x\to 1$ as $x\to 0$, so $o(y)=o(x)$.

---

For more general exponent $\alpha$, you need to take some care. When $u,v$ positive, the mean value theorem means that:

$$u^\alpha-v^{\alpha}= \alpha c^{\alpha-1}(u-v)$$

for some $c$ between $u,v$.

In particular then, when $x$ is close enough to zero so that $f(x),p(x)$ are bounded away from zero, then:

$$f(x)^\alpha-p(x)^{\alpha} = (f(x)-p(x))c_x$$ where $c_x$ is bounded, so if $f(x)-p(x)=o(x^n)$ then $f(x)^\alpha-p(x)^{\alpha}=o(x^n)$, too.

This latter part is incomplete, however, when $\alpha$ is not a positive integer, since $p(x)^\alpha$ is not a polynomial. Here, you need to apply the generalized binomial theorem to show that $$p(x)^\alpha = (1+xp_1(x))^\alpha = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{k}x^kp_1^k(x)$$ when $|xp_1(x)|<1$. You can show that $$p(x)^\alpha = 1+\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{\alpha}{k}x^kp_1(x)^k\right) + o(x^n)$$

Comment: if   you Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial of degree nn such that $p(0)=1.$ is my proof in this case correct

Comment: Your proof is not a proof, because, as I stated in the comments above, your statement is imprecise - it is entirely unclear what you are trying to prove. There is a whole lot missing in the $\ldots$. @Educ

Comment: check the picture

Comment: The picture is imprecise and sloppy too. It is quite possible that the context is just what I proved above, but the picture is just a vague suggestion, not a rigorous statement. The key to such comments in a paper/book is that they are guides, but a rigorous statement is required before you can prove it. As for your proof, you set let $y=\ldots +o(x^{n-1})$ but that doesn't mean anything. (Then you use capital $Y$, which is a no-no. Pick a case.) But the key is to make a precise statement *before you try to prove anything.*

Comment: so would you suggest me an edit ike $\biggl(p(x)+o(x^{n-1})\biggr)^{\alpha}=(p(x)+o(x^{n-1}))$ with $p(0)=1$ $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: No, because that won't be true. You don't get the same $p(x)$, and you certainly wouldn't want to assert it for any $\alpha$. First, just remove that $n-1$ - it is noise. Replace it with $n$. Look at the theorem *I've stated.* $(p(x)+o(x^{n}))^k=p(x)^k+o(x^{n})$. Now, $p(x)^k$ is *another* polynomial, not the original polynomial. You'd have to take care with general $\alpha$ - my proof assumes $\alpha$ is a positive integer. It is probably generally true, though, using the mean value theorem.

Comment: my goal was just to understand this equality $$(1+\ldots+o(x^{n-1}))^4=(1+\ldots+o(x^{n-1}))$$ in the picture but could you edit my post to make me understand wjy the author write $(1+\ldots+o(x^{n-1}))^4=(1+\ldots+o(x^{n-1}))$

Comment: The author wrote that for brevity. He means exactly what I wrote. The $\ldots$ on the left side are not meant to be the same as the $\ldots$ on the right side. It was just sloppy writing.

Comment: so cloud you edit my question

Comment: could you elaborate the part when you used mean value theorem for $u,v$ and for $f(x)$ and $q(x)$

Comment: "Could you elaborate" is too unspecific - I could spend a lot of time elaborating each part of that, when you only are confused on one point. What step did you not understand? @Educ.

Comment: i tired ti apply the mean value  $f ' (c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}.$ to get  $f(x)^\alpha-p(x)^{\alpha} = (f(x)-p(x))c_x$ but no luck

Comment: Wrong function for the mean value theorem. Let $h(x)=u^\alpha$. Apply mean value theorem to that, in general, for positive $u,v$, then for $u=f(x)$ and $v=p(x)$. @Educ Note that $h'(c)=\alpha c^{\alpha-1}$ is bounded when $c>\frac{1}{2}$, for example. We can pick $x$ close enough to zero so that $\frac{1}{2}<f(x),p(x)<\frac{3}{2}.$

Comment: Sorry, that should have been $h(x)=x^\alpha$.

Comment: Very good interpretation of the confusing result mentioned in question. And even more detailed is the proof and explanation. +1 from my end.

Answer (score 0):

It looks confuse, I'm not sure is totally correct. Do it by induction, it's easier !

$$(1+o(1))^4=1+o(1)$$

Let $g(x)=1+...+x^{n-1}$,
$$(1+x...+x^n+o(x^n))^4=\Big(1+x\big(g(x)+o(x^{n-1})\big)\Big)^4=
...$$